# Extending element beyond it's parent borders

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Imagine you have two adjacent columns. The first (left most) is the primary navigation and the second is the secondary navigation. To the right of these is the actual content.

I have links in both columns as unordered lists. The selected links in each are highlighted by changing the background colour.  The final part of the design is that the selected items needs to 'stickout' on the right hand side with a pointed arrow design (for which I have been provided an image for).

This is what I am having trouble with. I need to position an image to the very right of the `PrimaryNavigationSelected`. I am trying to extend the li element beyond it's parent borders and attach the arrow image as background. **Is this the best way to do this? Can you make an li element extend beyond the borders of its parent?**

The system is for a help like system that will be using an embedded IE7 control but the design is planned to be used eventually for the online help.

Code below: Note - the SecondaryNavigation is similar to Primary except for a change in colours and I don't feel comfortable posting over 160 lines of CSS. If you can show how to do it to the primary navigation I could make that extend to secondary.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="PrimaryNavigation">
<ul>
<li class="PrimaryNavigationDeselected"><a href="#">Primary Navigation Goes Here</a></li>
<li class="PrimaryNavigationDeselected"><a href="#">Primary Navigation Goes Here</a></li>
<li class="PrimaryNavigationSelected"><a href="#">Primary Navigation Goes Here</a></li>
<li class="PrimaryNavigationDeselected"><a href="#">Primary Navigation Goes Here</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="SecondaryNavigation">
<ul>
<li class="SecondaryNavigationSelected"><a href="#">Secondary Navigation Goes Here</a></li>
<li class="SecondaryNavigationDeselected"><a href="#">Secondary Navigation Goes Here</a></li>
<li class="SecondaryNavigationDeselected"><a href="#">Secondary Navigation Goes Here</a></li>
<li class="SecondaryNavigationDeselected"><a href="#">Secondary Navigation Goes Here</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#PrimaryNavigation {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
background-color: #2BB1E4;
}

#PrimaryNavigation * {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}

#PrimaryNavigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 44px 0 0 0; 
}

#PrimaryNavigation li {
    padding: .2em 0;
    padding-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#PrimaryNavigation a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.PrimaryNavigationDeselected {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.PrimaryNavigationDeselected:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.PrimaryNavigationSelected {
    margin: 1em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0079A7;
}

.PrimaryNavigationSelected:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0079A7;
}
```

Comment: Or, please provide your image so that exact match can be provided.

Comment: They are simply triangles 29 pixels high and 8 wide.

Comment: I would try and host the design I was provided as illustration of what I mean if it wasn't covered in the company name and logo.

Comment: If I understand right then you want to display #PrimaryNavigation at the left then when hovered it should display an image then SecondaryNavigation should be displayed which is like submenu?

Comment: The designers want the selected PrimaryNavigation list element to jutt out into the SecondaryNavigation. And then the selected SecondaryNavigation to jutt out into the Content.  The jutt is supposed to be done with a triangular image.  I am now trying to place the image with JS.

Comment: JS isn't going to work as the li style for top is auto so I can't get its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working.

Firstly the environment it will end up in is an IE7 control so I had to add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

To get the code to work in IE7 after I managed to get it working in IE8.

For IE8 I needed to add the following to `PrimaryNavigationSelected`:

```
padding-right: 8px; 
right: -8px; 
margin-left: -8px; 
color: #FFFFFF;
background: transparent url(arrow.png) 100% 50% no-repeat;
```

But for IE7 you need to remove the `right` and `margin-left` properties.

Strange, but true.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your strategy should be to include background image in the right side of the li and then add padding-right so that your text appears left of the image.

Or you can also think of using :after selector.

Comment: Tried using the `:after` selector but that places the image at the end of the text and not outside the box model - it is still within the boundary of the PrimaryNavigation.

Comment: Similar thing occurs with using background image and padding right.

Comment: Please post code for better understanding; but you may need to look into [CSS Triangles](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) too.

Comment: I know about CSS triangles.  I've actually given up on trying to do it in pure CSS and trying at finding the top,right position of the selected element and placing the element there.  The right is easy - it is set to 20%.  Just need to find the top of the element with `class="PrimaryNavigationSelected"`